# harmony 1100 remote on a custom ubuntu boxee comp

Tags: ubuntu, remote-control, boxee

I have a old computer with hdmi output that I installed ubuntu and boxee on.  I want to set it up so I can control it with my harmony 1100 remote control.

How can I do this?

Alternatively how can I set up any remote to work with boxee there?  (even IR and I can set up the 1100 from there)

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu Support pages](http://www.ubuntu.com/support) would probably be the most helpful. If the old computer has a CD drive then installation off of a [live disc image](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) would be the route to go.